# Ajax Response new Browser Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to sent $.Post request In my web page and response about after 1-5 sec.

my problem is

If I make a Ajax request and then open site same browser new tab it wait for previous tab request result.

But I don't want to wait in new tab page.
How can solve this problem.

Tanks for reply.

**For example :** domain.com/index.php open a web page which has a search form.

first ,  when a form submit  $.POST request start and goto for results. respose time about 5 - 10 sec.

second,  before get response , if i open new browser tab and goto same url (domain.com/index.php) when page loading is waiting because  previous request is not responsed yet.

I dont want to wait in new tab.

Comment: can you clarify that a little, what is the content for the new tab. is that from the response?

Comment: Show us some code. But my guess is that you have to move your "open me a new tab" code out of your ajax callback

Comment: In Ajax success call back, generate new browser tab. Like this :  window.open('target-file', '_blank');

Comment: For example : domain.com/index.php open a web page which has a search form.

first , when a form submit $.POST request start and goto for results. respose time about 5 - 10 sec.

second, before get response , if i open new browser tab and goto same url (domain.com/index.php) when page loading is waiting because previous request is not responsed yet.

I dont want to wait in new tab.